# How to display horizontally a list of names (Strings) and make them each clickable?

Tags: android, string, android-listview, onclick, append

I am looking for a way to display in may Android app a list of names horizontally (maybe in a TextView) and to make them all clickable. The names are pulled from an online database with their own id, which id points to their profile activities for more information about each person.

ListView is not an option I guess because its vertical nature, Is there a simple way to do this, like appending each name with their own click capability?

Thanks!!

Comment: you can use an horizontal implementation of listview. For example: https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView or https://github.com/MeetMe/Android-HorizontalListView

Comment: why you don't use `HorizontalScrollView` ?

Comment: @LucianoRodríguez - I was hoping for some built in solution, I wanted to keep this simple, without implementing another external library.

Comment: @EdmondTamas you could check those libraries to give you an idea of how you can implement your horizontal custom view yourself.

Answer (score 0):

i hope the following library will help you:

https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to use some internal, built in solution.

Comment: it is having only one custom view group file based on that you can achieve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

To create a horizontal `ListView` you don't need any **external** library. I have found an article on web that shows how to do that.

http://sandyandroidtutorials.blogspot.in/2013/06/horizontal-listview-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

The suggestions were probabily ok, but were not quite what I wanted, I came up with a solution like this:

```
for (int i=0; i< contacts.length();i++){
                        JSONObject json = contacts.getJSONObject(i);    
                        final String names = json.getString("names");
                        final String uerIds = json.getString("userIds");

                        final TextView[] likers = new TextView[10];

                        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.likers);
                        //setContentView(layout);
                        likers[i] = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                        likers[i].setText(names + ", ");
                        likers[i].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#d52e2e"));
                        likers[i].setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
                        likers[i].setTextSize(13);                  

                        layout.addView(likers[i]);

                        likers[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(View v) {                               
                                Intent in= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserProfile.class);
                                in.putExtra("user", names);
                                in.putExtra("userId", uerIds);
                                startActivity(in);                              
                            }
                        });
```

I have created dynamically a TextView for each name, together with OnClickListeners. Hope to help anyone looking for a simple solution.